# Assembly - Convert user-entered string to hex equivalent

Tags: assembly, hex, ascii, 68000, easy68k

I'm working on a program in assembly (in Easy68K) that prompts a user to enter a memory address. The program then converts each of those ASCII chars into their hex equivalents. I can convert the hex just fine, but I'm running into a problem.

If the user enters A234567F, this is stored (in A1) as 8 bytes, but the valid memory address hex equivalent is only 4 bytes (2 words, 1 longword). I can iterate through each character and convert it to its hex-digit equivalent, no problem. But I can't figure out how to "concatenate" them together, so to speak.

I don't want there to be a separate byte of storage for "A" and a separate byte of storage for "2". I want "A2" to be stored in the same byte of storage.

And so, in this example, what I'd like is for the storage to look like this for this example:

Memory address `$00000000` should hold the value `$A2`.

`$00000001` holds `$34`

`$00000002` holds `$56`

`$00000003` holds `$7F`

Then, if I do a `MOVE.L` starting from address `$00000000` into D1, then D1 would contain the value `$A234567F`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Shift by 4 bits then add the next hex digit.

Comment: It sounds like the user input already *is* in hex (a serialization format for binary numbers), and you want to deserialize it into a single binary integer in a register.  Not convert *to* hex.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! I don't naturally see the answer when it comes to bit-shifting, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not super sure what you mean, but from my perspective, the user input is the ASCII representation of hex digits, and I want to convert to the numerical representation. Then I want to store that representation in a register, as hex.